# How get long arrow to point at line between two boxes in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I am trying, and trying to get a long arrow to point at the line between the two boxes, please see the Graphviz below.  What do I do wrong??

---

In this Graphviz:

```
digraph W1 {
    rankdir=LR
    nodesep = 0.05
    
    node [shape=box width="0.8" height="0.5" fontsize="10"]
    edge [weight=1]
    
    3 [label = "Compound 2"]
    4 [label = "Compound 1"]
    5 [label = "Compound 3"]
    Nod1 [shape=diamond style=filled label="" height=.01 width=.01]
    
    {
        3 -> Nod1 
        4 -> Nod1
        Nod1 -> 5
        {
            rank = same
            Nod1
            3
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: arrow to point at the line between the two boxes made with graphviz]

Comment: It works for me.. what is wrong?

Comment: Even if graphviz creates some output, it's hard to read and understand what you're trying to achieve. Inconsistent use of `;`, inconsistent indentation, inconsistent spaces, nodes are listed several times, different edge defaults follow each other without any edge defined in between, ...

Comment: I also see the graph, but I got an error message on (for instance) line 6 (I think the comma is invalid). Don't you see the errors? What tool are you using ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comments! I found out that if I change "nodesep = 0.05" to "nodesep = 0.3" I manage to separate the boxes more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the line (edge) length with the [`minlen`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/minlen/) attribute for desired edge.

In your example it is enough to change the line `3 -> Nod1` to:

```
3 -> Nod1 [minlen=10]
```